# How do I return value in the cell to the right

Tags: excel, vlookup

I think I need a vlookup formula for what I want to do but I am not sure how to word it.

I want excel to return the supplier name to the right of the relevant price, so I want to look up the prices in column A using the range C:J and return the supplier to the right of the corresponding value. See below:

```
A       B   C       D       E       F       G       H       I       J
R 65.80     R 53.52 Bi-Rite R 7.40  Makro   R 12.25 Usavesa R 32.88 Silverlake
```

TIA

Comment: How do you tell a supplier is the right one? Where do you lookup - is it only in the range C:J? Then what if the exact price is not in the list?

Answer (score 0):

If your required price is in say A6, then something like the following might suit:

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(A6,1:1,0)+1)
```

Comment: So if I am using the price in A to look up in C,E,G & I in order to return the name in either D,F,H or J?